# How to configure Clion to run gdb commands before start?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gdb, remote-debugging, clion, multiarch

I am able to remote debug RapberryPi application with `vscode` config saying

```
            "gdbpath": "gdb-multiarch",
            "autorun": [
                "set architecture arm_any"
            ]
```

What is equivalent setting in CLion? I need `set architecture arm_any` run in `gdb-multiarch` after connect.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue today. My (somewhat hacky!) solution:
I created a GDB script file in my repo which contains nothing but my initialization code as well as a reset command at the end:

```
set architecture arm_any

monitor reset halt
```

I then told CLion to `source` my script as a "reset command" in my debugger settings
[as shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBA3J.png).

Note that you have to tick the "after download" box in order to get your configuration to take effect as soon as you start the debugger. Otherwise you'll have to manually reset first.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-debugger-options.html#gdbinit-lldbinit):

> If your project requires more configuration options for debugging, you can create a custom initialization file, .gdbinit for GDB or .lldbinit for LLDB, and place it under the project root. This file can be shared through VCS along with other project files.